# When allocate 2D array dynamically, why there is 12byte gap by each row in memory

Tags: c++, arrays

As I describe above, always there is 12 Byte gap by each row when I allocate 2 dimension array dynamically.

In that code, I expected **ppa[1]** to be 0x1005626e4. But result is 0x1005626f0. I know dynamic allocation may not allocated in contiguous space. But there is always at least 12 Byte gap.(Actually some times each row allocated in different space)

I know when allocate in heap, need some space for store information. Eg size, type..
Is that reason of 12 Byte? If someone know real reason of 12 Byte tell me about that.

#### Code

```
int** ppa;
  
ppa = new int*[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  ppa[i] = new int[5];
  cout << "ppa[" << i << "]: " << ppa[i] << endl;
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
    cout << "&ppa[" << i << "][" << j << "]: " << &ppa[i][j] << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

### output

```
ppa[0]: 0x1005626d0
&ppa[0][0]: 0x1005626d0
&ppa[0][1]: 0x1005626d4
&ppa[0][2]: 0x1005626d8
&ppa[0][3]: 0x1005626dc
&ppa[0][4]: 0x1005626e0

ppa[1]: 0x1005626f0
&ppa[1][0]: 0x1005626f0
&ppa[1][1]: 0x1005626f4
&ppa[1][2]: 0x1005626f8
&ppa[1][3]: 0x1005626fc
&ppa[1][4]: 0x100562700

ppa[2]: 0x100562710
&ppa[2][0]: 0x100562710
&ppa[2][1]: 0x100562714
&ppa[2][2]: 0x100562718
&ppa[2][3]: 0x10056271c
&ppa[2][4]: 0x100562720
```

#### My Test Environment

OS: OSX 64bit system

IDE: Xcode

Comment: It may be an alignment issue as well. It is possible that the allocator returns addresses that are multiples of a 16-byte address.

Comment: the posted code is C++, so the tag C should be removed.  C and C++ are two different languages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you do is creating a [*jagged array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) where there's no requirement that sub-arrays have to be allocated contiguously.

You simply get what the memory allocator gives you.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out above, you are allocating references of 3 different 1-D arrays (to ppa[i]) afterwards. However, these 1-D arrays may be assigned any memory address in the memory(no specific pattern of 12byte gap). The only ensured thing is that the elements inside 3 of these 1-D arrays will be contiguous.

Note:- If you create array such as "int ppa[3][5]", then all the elements will be contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some internal information about allocated block is stored there.